# What's the best practice for executing a sequence of R scripts

Tags: r, bash

I have a list of R scripts that I need to run in sequence. That is, I need to wait until completion of the first one before moving with the second one. This is the sequence:

```
one.R
two.R
three.R
four.R
```

Should I write a short bash script calling all the scripts in sequence? How should I write it? What line should I add at the top of the R script?

Also, my scripts need to share R objects one with the other. If I call the scripts from bash they will still use a common R workspace?

Comment: If you want to use a common R workspace, you will have to start a R session by bash and call your scripts using "source()" commando in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your scripts need to share objects, I would simply create one script where functionality has been cut up into functions. The structure could be somehting like:

```
main_script.R
support_functions_A.R
support_functions_B.R
```

Then in `main_script.R` you use `source` to load the functions into your R session, e.g. `source("support_functions_A.R")`. This has the advantage of having the main functionality in one place, at a nicer abstraction level. If the number of support functions grows, you could also consider creating an R package for this. This is especially useful when your code is also used by other people.

Calling the scripts in sequence using a bash script can only work if they do not need to share the same R workspace. I would avoid chaining together R functionality like this, and focus on writing functions in stead of separate scripts.

If you need to run an R script as a script within bash, you can add:

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript
```

at the top of your R script, and make the script executable using `chmod`.